# Get Resource from ClassLoader with leading slash

Tags: resources, classloader

i'm trying to access an external method of third part jar by reflection.

1) i add external jar to classpath by "addUrl" method of system class loader

2) i retrieve class type, method, then i invoke the method and it's all working

I decompile part of external jar:

```
public class Deploy
{
    ...

    public static Deploy init()
    {
        InputStream i = Deploy.class
        .getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(
        "/com/example/props");
    }
}
```

Using the third part component this call works, because it reads correctly "props" file.
But in my code it returns null, intead of:
"/com/example/props" 
i've tried:
"com/example/props"
without slash and it works.

How can i do to have that code working in my application? Any workaroud? (i have to call it through reflection)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are assuming the JVM class loader is a URLClassLoader, then be aware that the JDK does not guarantee this, and it will likely not be true as of Java 9 ([JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)).
2. URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream should not be passed a leading "/", so that is likely a bug in the third party JAR.  Your best option is to load the third party JAR in a custom ClassLoader (e.g., your own subclass of URLClassLoader) that can handle that leading "/" (e.g., override getResourceAsStream, remove the "/", and delegate to URLClassLoader).

Comment: It is true that `URLClassLoader.getResource` should not have a leading `/` in Java SE, but I found a leading `/` works in Java EE. But I do not know why.

Comment: Perhaps a bug in the implementation, perhaps just lenient for directory-based classpaths.  I would not rely on that even if it works since even though there are no specific requirements for class loader resources, there are well-established conventions.

Comment: I have figured out the reason. I checked the source code of Tomcat, and found it overrides the `classloader` logic of JDK in its `WebappClassLoader`.